# loop through divs and extract text using simplehtmldom

Tags: php, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

I am using simplehtmldom to grab the html from a site.  I then search for all the divs on the page and 
display the innertext where the word count is greater than 300.  To do this I iterate with foreach.

```
$findDivs = $html->find('div');

foreach($findDivs as $findDiv) {
  $wordCount = explode(' ', $findDiv->outertext);
  $wordCount = count($wordCount);
  if($wordCount <= 300) {
    $findDiv->outertext = '';
   }
   else {
     echo $findDiv->outertext . '<br />';
  }
}
```

The problem that I have is that the results are duplicated 6 times. I can only assume that it is because all the divs are looped over for each iteration. However, I am not certain what technique I could use to ensure that each div is only assessed once.

Comment: Iterate the divs recursively, do not process a div's children if it contains 300+ words.

Comment: Please provide sample html. You are otherwise unlikely to get constructive help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why, but this has solved my problem.

I added the '1' parameter in the $html->find('div',1);

So the working code looks like:

```
$findDivs = $html->find('div',1);  //add a 1 to the divs. this works as the script now only loops once.

foreach($findDivs as $findDiv) {
  $wordCount = explode(' ', $findDiv->outertext);
  $wordCount = count($wordCount);
  if($wordCount <= 300) {
    $findDiv->outertext = '';
   }
   else {
     echo $findDiv->outertext . '<br />';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want the `innertext` but your code states `outertext` - I think that's the cause for the duplication.

```
foreach($html->find('div') as $findDiv) {
  $wordCount = explode(' ', $findDiv->innertext);
  $wordCount = count($wordCount);
  if($wordCount > 300) {
    echo $findDiv->outertext . '<br />';
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi David, thank you but I am afraid that I tried innertext, outertext and plaintext, and I have the same results in terms of duplication each time.